# Как изменить цвет текста названия приложения в AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar?

Tags: java, android

[image: anna_prog]

Изменить цвет фона проблем не составляет, а вот как изменить цвет текста уже всю голову сломала и весь инет облазила. Как этот текст правильно называется?

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#0380DA</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name="colorTabText">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_head_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/text_head_color</item>
</style>
```

Здесь основной цвет и будет отвечать за цвет названия.

Comment: Это работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

ID заголовка ActionBar скрыт. Это внутренний механизм и доступ к нему не может быть получен обычным путем. Вы можете получить ссылку используя  `Resources.getIdentifier` и после использовать `View.findViewById`.

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
Теперь вы можете использовать этот `Id` с `TextView`

TextView abTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
abTitle.setTextColor(colorId);
```